# Autowired field is null when testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm trying to test a simple Predicate I have in my application. This predicate uses a repository to check for some data, but when I test it the repository is always `null`, even if it works well in the real context.

Here is the predicate:

```
@Slf4j
public class NameChangePredicate implements ValidationPredicate {

    @Autowired
    NameChangeRepository nameChangeRepository;

    String errorCode;
    GeographicZone zone;

    public NameChangePredicate(String errorCode, GeographicZone zone) {
        super();
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    /**
     * Test the condition
     *
     * @param response the {@link ValidationServiceResponse}
     * @return true if valid
     */
    @Override
    public boolean test(ValidationServiceResponse response) {
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(response.getClass()) && zone != null) {
            List<NameChange> nameChanges = nameChangeRepository.findAllByGeographicZoneId(zone.getId());

            if (nameChanges.stream().anyMatch(n -> n.getClasses().stream().anyMatch(response.getClass()::equalsIgnoreCase))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        throw new ValidationException(this.errorCode);
    }
}
```

Here is my simple test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public class NameChangeTest {

    @Autowired
    NameChangeRepository nameChangeRepository;

    @Autowired
    GeographicZoneRepository geographicZoneRepository;

    private GeographicZone zone;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        ....
    }

    @Test
    public void testNameChangeParameter() {
        final NameChangePredicate predicate = new NameChangePredicate("", zone);
        List<NameChange> list = nameChangeRepository.findAll();
        Assert.assertEquals("There should be 4 NameChange in db", 4, list.size());

        ValidationServiceResponse response = new ValidationServiceResponse();
        response.setBookingClass("C");
        Assert.assertTrue("Name change should be eligible", predicate.test(response));
    }
}
```

But in test context the `@Autowired` repository of the `predicate` is `null`, probably because it's field injection.
Is there a way to use constructor injection with other parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Slf4j
public class NameChangePredicate implements ValidationPredicate {

    String errorCode;
    GeographicZone zone;
    NameChangeRepository nameChangeRepository;

    public NameChangePredicate(String errorCode, GeographicZone zone, NameChangeRepository nameChangeRepository) {
        super();
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.zone = zone;
        this.nameChangeRepository = nameChangeRepository;
    }
...
}

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public class NameChangeTest {

    @Autowired
    NameChangeRepository nameChangeRepository;

    ....

    @Test
    public void testNameChangeParameter() {
        final NameChangePredicate predicate = new NameChangePredicate("", zone, nameChangeRepository);
    }
}
```

EDITED: Since `NameChangePredicate` is not a Spring `@Component` itself you need to get a reference to the repository from some other component that acts as the client of this class. If you could design the class as a component then Spring would inject the repository automatically to the constructor when you run it "in the real context", just as it autowires it in the test. But of course in that case you would need to get rid somehow of the constructor parameters `errorCode` and `zone`, which doesn't seem very convenient in this example.

Comment: It works but with this way in "the real context" I will have to pass my repository to each of my predicates

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing two things here: Spring configuration and constructor.

When you are creating an instance of `NameChangePredicate` with the constructor, Spring is not working and not initializing it.

Not sure how to correct your example but looks like your design is not quite correct. `NameChangePredicate` does two things: acts as a predicate and holds the logic for the two fields. I suggest to separate these two fields `String errorCode;  GeographicZone zone;` into a separate class and inject it in `NameChangePredicate` in the same way as `NameChangeRepository`.